# How to use Coroutine inside a FloatingActionButton/Button Click event

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a FloatingActionButton, which when clicked will download few URL's from the web. I want to start this function from inside the setOnClickListener, and then let it does all the processing in the background.

I already did what I wanted to do using AsyncTask, but then someone suggested to use coroutines.

Inside the activity:

```
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
           
            val currentChapUrl = "https://www.novel.com/chap1.html"  
            GlobalScope.launch { downloadChapters(applicationContext,currentChapUrl) } 
        }
```

The downloadChapters function looks like this:

```
suspend fun downloadChapters(context : Context, startingChapUrl : String) : String {
   //download chapters.
   //show some toast messages

}
```

The app crashes on clicking the button.

Logcat:

```
2020-08-01 17:03:38.559 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:38.559 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.095 6937-6937/com.example.daoreader I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-08-01 17:03:39.124 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.125 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.163 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.163 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.208 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.209 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-08-01 17:03:39.211 6937-7086/com.example.daoreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.daoreader, PID: 6937
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.<init>(Toast.java:336)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:103)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:256)
        at com.example.daoreader.WebviewActivity.downloadChapters(WebviewActivity.kt:65)
        at com.example.daoreader.WebviewActivity$onCreate$1$1.invokeSuspend(WebviewActivity.kt:32)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
    
    
    --------- beginning of system
2020-08-01 17:03:39.257 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.257 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.307 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.307 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.394 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.394 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.487 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.487 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.565 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.566 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.581 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa205000: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa2034c0)
2020-08-01 17:03:39.595 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa205000: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa2034c0)
2020-08-01 17:03:39.658 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.658 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:39.714 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa205000: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa2034c0)
2020-08-01 17:03:39.727 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9232d500 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x92021280
2020-08-01 17:03:40.051 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:40.051 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:40.094 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2020-08-01 17:03:40.094 6937-6985/com.example.daoreader E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is crashing, because you are showing `Toast` not in the Main Thread.

`GlobalScope.launch` defaultly run code in another Thread which is `Dispatchers.Default`.

So what you need to do, before showing `Toast`, you should change the thread to Main Thread like this

```
suspend fun downloadChapters(context : Context, startingChapUrl : String) : String {
   //download chapters.
   
   withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
       // Show Toast here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using `GlobalScope`. You should use `lifecycleScope` to start a coroutine inside your view.

You need to add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:{version}` to your gradle file first.

Assuming that you want to show in a Toast what `downloadChapters` returns then I would do it like this:

Inside an Activity:

```
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val message = downloadChapters(this@MyActivity, "https://www.novel.com/chap1.html")
        //Show toast here
    }
}
```

Inside a Fragment:

```
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        val message = downloadChapters(context, "https://www.novel.com/chap1.html")
        //Show toast here
    }
}
```

Since `lifecycleScope.launch` runs on the Main thread you must change its context to `Dispatchers.IO` during `downloadChapters` so your method should look something like this:

```
suspend fun downloadChapters(context : Context, startingChapUrl : String) : String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    //download chapters.
    "This is my message" //Return your message here
}
```

You can't update your view inside `downloadChapters` unless you move to `Dispatchers.Main` before you do it or an exception will be thrown. I'd rather do it after calling that method.